# Importing modules at parent path

Tags: python, module, path

My project is: mymodule.py and test/test.py

In test.py I put: `from myfunc import mymodule`

but python 3.6 answers: 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'titalicapi'`

If instead I put (after reading about similar questions):
`from ... import mymodule`
the answer now is:
`ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

How I can let test.py to work? thanks!

Comment: Do you have a `__init__.py` in the module folder?

Comment: it's empty and it doesn't make any effect

Answer (score 1):

could you perhaps show your file path? That'll help a lot.

```
Sample File Path
 mainfolder
 |-test.py
 |    
 |-workfiles
    |- myfunc
```

If your current project looks something like this, you can impprt the function and use workfiles.myfunc to access the function

```
from workfiles.myfunc import myfunc
```

I would suggest putting your main file in the root folder and sub-files/modules in other sub-folders for easier access! Hope this helped :)